# Need to implement a recursive and rolling estimate scheme on a model

Tags: r, forecasting

As part of a homework assignment, we are asked the following question:

> Using the same data set as in Exercise 3 and for house price growth, run several regression models with one, two, three, and four lags of price growth in the right‐ hand side of the model. Analyze the regression results. Choose your favorite model and implement a recursive and a rolling estimation scheme. Plot the time series of the estimates of the regression coefficients and observe how much they change over time.

I can't seem to get this to work in R. This is my Code so far:

```
PRQ <- read_excel("~/Desktop/144/HW2/Chapter4_exercises_data.xls",sheet = "Exercise 3")

price_ts<-ts(PRQ$P,start = 1980:2, freq=4)

r_price <- diff(log(price_ts)) ##growth rate

lag<-append(NA, r_price[-length(r_price)])

lag2<-append(NA, lag[-length(lag)])

lag3<-append(NA,lag2[-length(lag2)])

lag4<-append(NA, lag3[-length(lag3)])

y1<-lm(r_price~lag)

y2<-lm(r_price~lag+lag2)

y3<-lm(r_price~lag+lag2+lag3)

y4<-lm(r_price~lag+lag2+lag3+lag4)

summary(y1)

summary(y2)

summary(y3)

summary(y4)
```

---

In case my question is unclear, this is the [textbook description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjnbT.png) of what I need to do. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Check `?rollapply` from package `zoo`. There's a rolling regression in the examples at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to use `ARIMA`. If you have to use LM tell me and i'll come up with something new.

```
fit1 = arima(price_ts, order = c(1L, 0L, 0L))
```

This will give you 1 AR term (lag). You can continue in this fashion to get the rest.

**EDIT**

I read your textbook and we need to change this around a little. I will use simulated data and show you the answer for 1 lag. You should be able to figure out the rest on your own.

First, simulate the data:

```
tsdat = arima.sim(model=list(ar=-0.5),n=400)arima.sim(model=list(ar=-0.5),n=400))
```

Then, we need to fit a model on the first t terms. I will set `t = 200`

```
library(forecast)
t = 200
fit = arima(tsdat[1:t], order = c(1L, 0L, 0L))
```

We can look at the details of the model if we are interested

```
> summary(fit)

Call:
arima(x = tsdat[1:t], order = c(1L, 0L, 0L))

Coefficients:
          ar1  intercept
      -0.4556    -0.0211
s.e.   0.0629     0.0462

sigma^2 estimated as 0.9007:  log likelihood = -273.45,  aic = 552.9
```

The parameter is fairly close to what I specified for the simulation. You won't know what it actually should be though in your case.

Finally, we can forecast 1 point out.

```
forecast(fit, h= 1)
    Point Forecast     Lo 80     Hi 80     Lo 95    Hi 95
201     -0.4320716 -1.648363 0.7842197 -2.292229 1.428085
```

Create a for loop to go through and refit the model adding in more data and saving the forecast results.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am still a little bit confused about how this implements the recursive/rolling estimation? As a layman, this seems to just lag the time series. I'm sorry if this should be obvious, I'm in a forecasting class where we have to learn the subject along with R so it is a bit overwhelming lol.

Comment: @KodaJ so what you're looking for is y_t = theta*x_t-1, right?

Comment: @KodaJ read this page. I believe it's what you're looking for unless I misunderstood https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/3

Comment: The goal is to collect, "a sequence of 1‐step ahead forecasting errors {et,1, et+1,1, . . . . . et+j,1, . . . . . eT-1,1}." so that they can be  plotted. The way I understand it is the coefficients of the  different e. @Kristofersen I looked at the page but it doesn't have the R code.

Comment: @KodaJ right predicting off of lagged values of the time series. So you can use arima to get your fit. You can load the library forecast and call forecast() on the fit to predict future values. My response hasn't been transformed so that would need to be done.

Comment: I also added a screen shot of my textbook description of what needs to be done to my original post.  @Kristofersen Just refreshed and saw your response. I will try that thank you!

Comment: @KodaJ take a look now. I think i have included all you need to figure the rest out.